# UIGestureRecognizer in storyboard can use multiple views?

Tags: ios, ios5, storyboard, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

I created a lot of Views and Buttons, then i created ISwipeGestureRecognizer graphically. And added a lot of views to recognizers "Referencing Outlet Collection". And swipe gesture works on all my views. How is it possible? Storyboard automatically creates different SwipeRecognizers for every connected UIView?

[image]

I can't add more views programmatically, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never tried what you describe with the Storyboard, so I cannot answer directly, but I can suggest a way to verify whether multiple gesture recognizers are created: in your gesture action method, add an `NSLog` statement to log the address of the recognizer (this is the first argument that is passed to the action method). In this way, you will verify whether the same recognizer is reused.

Also, log the `recognizer.view` property to see what is going on under the hood. If you get the same result for all the cases, then it can be optimistically inferred that the `UISwipeRecognizer` is not using internally its `view` property for anything and that that information is stored only for your action callback to be able to access it.

What would be a mystery is that you got only one gesture recognizer and different values for the `view` property. This would imply that the property value is changed on the fly, but I would not be able to explain how.

Comment: I've just tryed this solution. Really, there are multiple recognizers instead of single. Thanx you.

Comment: You are welcome! I had no idea about this feature of the Storyboard; good to know...

Answer (score 2):

You can connect a gesture recognizer to multiple views in Interface Builder. They will all send the proper messages when touched. However, you can't detect which view was touched using the recognizer's view property. It will always point to the same view regardless of the view that is touched.

I don't believe you can do the same with code. Yes, that's odd.

So as long as you don't care which view triggered the touch, you're all good.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a single gesture recognizer to as many views as you like, either in code or using interface builder. To do this you use the `addGestureRecognizer:` method of `UIView`.  Note that you add the recognizer to the view, not the other way around.

Comment: You might want to try that. Recognizers have a `view` property for a reason, just as views have a `superview` property (notice how the words are not plural?).